# Remove the object when the array string match in object key javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

I'm working with someone else code, trying to not breaking other function from the application, but basically I need to remove the object when the condition match.

The question I asked before will remove the object, but not in the different code base, so hoping someone can give me some idea.

Thanks for the help!

```
const data = {   
   '123': {
        'name': 'Part 1',
        'size': '20',
        'qty' : '50'
    },
    '5678' : {
        'name': 'Part 2',
        'size': '15',
        'qty' : '60'
    },
   '9810' : {
        'name': 'Part 2',
        'size': '15',
        'qty' : '120'
    },
 }

// my code I tried work with:
const getValue = Object.keys(data).reduce((acc,id)=> {
   const condition = ['9810','5678'];
   if(acc[key]){
      // remove the object if the key match
      return !acc.includes(key[id])
   } else {
      // if not match just return the original object
      return acc
   }
},{})
```

Comment: What should the output be?

Comment: Also, it's `Object.keys` not `Object.key`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new object with the removed properties (which is probably a good idea), you should assign the value at the key to the accumulator, and you can use `Object.entries` to get both the key and value at once in the `reduce` callback. You can also use a Set instead of an array for less computational complexity (`Set.has` is `O(1)`, whereas `Array.includes` is `O(n)`):

```js
const data = {
  '123': {
    'name': 'Part 1',
    'size': '20',
    'qty': '50'
  },
  '5678': {
    'name': 'Part 2',
    'size': '15',
    'qty': '60'
  },
  '9810': {
    'name': 'Part 2',
    'size': '15',
    'qty': '120'
  },
}

const condition = new Set(['9810', '5678']);
const filteredData = Object.entries(data).reduce((acc, [key, val]) => {
  if (!condition.has(key)) {
    acc[key] = val;
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(filteredData);
```

If you want to actually remove the sub-object from the *existing* `data` object (mutating the `data` that you already have), then iterate with `forEach` and use `delete` to remove the property:

```js
const data = {
  '123': {
    'name': 'Part 1',
    'size': '20',
    'qty': '50'
  },
  '5678': {
    'name': 'Part 2',
    'size': '15',
    'qty': '60'
  },
  '9810': {
    'name': 'Part 2',
    'size': '15',
    'qty': '120'
  },
}

const condition = new Set(['9810', '5678']);
Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
  if (condition.has(key)) {
    delete data[key];
  }
});
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response. Is possible make the Key condition inside the reduce function? Because previous dev use that key generate an array from other condition inside reduce function. I can't move it out. Thanks!

Comment: Creating the array on every iteration results in a lot of unnecessary overhead, but you *can* put it inside the callback if you want. (If you create the `condition` array on every iteration, don't use a Set, because converting the array to a Set itself is an `O(n)` operation)

Answer (score 0):

To delete all objects in a sub-object that are contained in an array of keys, use `forEach` and `delete`.

```js
const data = {'123':{'name':'Part 1','size':'20','qty':'50'},'5678' :{'name':'Part 2','size':'15','qty':'60'},'9810' :{'name':'Part 2','size':'15','qty':'120'}};

const condition = ["5678", "9810"];

condition.forEach(key => delete data[key]);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Or if you want the other way around - *keeping* only the keys contained in the array:

```js
const data = {'123':{'name':'Part 1','size':'20','qty':'50'},'5678' :{'name':'Part 2','size':'15','qty':'60'},'9810' :{'name':'Part 2','size':'15','qty':'120'}};

const condition = ["5678", "9810"];

Object.keys(data).forEach(key => !condition.includes(key) ? delete data[key] : key);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response! Let me try this one out!